# Can you explain the relationship between groups, i.e a parent group

Tags: groups

Can you explain the relationship between groups, i.e. a parent group

I have set up a new group which includes members who are also part of a larger group.  What does it mean if I set it so the larger group, i.e. volunteers, is the parent of the smaller group, i.e. Monday weeders?

Thanks

Comment: ...and if that's not what you were wondering then feel free to clarify your question :)

Answer (score 5):

If your *monday weeders* group belongs to the *volunteers* group, then members of the *monday weeders* will be acted upon automatically as members of the *volunteers* group.  So when you send an email to the parent group of *volunteers* it will be sent to all the members of *monday weeders* and any other group that's a sub-group of *volunteers*.

Is that what you're wondering?

There's more information about groups here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/.